# Being V3/Having been V3/To be V3

Tags: grammar

Can someone help me? Which one is grammatically correct among these 3 sentences?

1.After the Civil War,an old slave was even reported being killed as he was learning to read.

2.After the Civil War,an old slave was even reported having been killed as he was learning to read.

3.After the Civil War,an old slave was even reported to be killed as he was learning to read.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, rather, that a better construction would be:

After the civil war, an old slave was even reported to have been killed as he was learning to read.

Even this can be improved, though. The problem with the above is, that it does not make it clear whether the slave was killed because he was learning to read, or simply that he was killed during the time that he was educating himself. So (if the intended meaning is what I believe) the following is even better:

After the civil war, an old slave was even reported to have been killed because he was learning to read.